# Cant turn layer back on

Tags: jquery, if-statement, layer, visible

I am working on a interactive map and I can turn the layer off but I cant turn it back on. I cant get the jQuery else to work.

```
$(function() {
    $("#BS").click(function () {
       if (avenzaViewer.isLayerVisible("BuyingScrapple"))
            avenzaViewer.setVisible("BuyingScrapple", true); 
        else
            avenzaViewer.setVisible("BuyingScrapple", false); 
    });
});
```